# Namespace errors when converting a project to VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, migration, compatibility

So I'm a fledgeling programmer that's been assigned to get to know an application that's been in development (in VS2005, then in 2008) for quite some time. Over the life of the project the naming conventions therein have become somewhat convoluted. For the sake of example, here is a piece of the naming structure.

> `_MegaCorp.sln`
>
> > `Application_Install`
> >
> > `Megacorp`
> >
> > > `DbResources.csproj`
> > >
> > > `Forms`
> > >
> > > > `Megacorp.Forms.Concept.csproj`
> > > >
> > > > > `Properties`
> > > > >
> > > > > `Resources`
> > > > >
> > > > > `Megacorp`
> > > > >
> > > > > > `Forms`
> > > > > >
> > > > > > > `Concept`
> > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > `xyz.cs`

It's maybe not the best way to organize information, but it works fine in VS2008. Updating to VS2010 shouldn't necessitate an overhaul of the existing code, right?

What's happening is this: when xyz calls for DbResources, visual studio is looking in Megacorp.Forms.Concept.Megacorp, not in the parent Megacorp folder. All the proper references and using statements are in order: as I said, everything works fine in VS2008. What's happening here?

```
    Error   826 The type or namespace name 'xxx' does not exist in the namespace 'MegaCorp.Forms.Concept.Megacorp.Forms.Concept' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:\x\y\c-sharp\Megacorp\Forms\Concept\ConstructEditor.Designer.cs   99  63  MegaCorp.Forms.Concept
```

UPDATE: If I add `global::` before each use of a class in xyz.cs, this resolves the problem. However, there are about 1,000,000 lines of code, and over 400 errors reported by the compiler. I'm sure that if I combed through each of the 400 errors, pasting `global::` before each one, more errors would arise. There must be another way to do this, because again, the solution comprises a very functional and in-use application compiled in VS2008.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hard to say but when you go to `References` in the project giving you the error, is everything ok?

Comment: No, some of the references to other modules in the solution are broken, because they won't compile, because of the aforementioned problem.

Comment: It does not follow there is another way to do this just because it is a functional program in 2005.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and found out that it is related to **Target Framework**. Check if all the added references are of solutions for same Target Framework.